# When to set stage event-listeners in an externally loaded SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there an event that would be triggered inside an externally loaded SWF, once that SWF has been loaded into another parent SWF and has had it's stage initialized?

I'm loading in an external SWF that has stage event-listeners added:

`stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stageClick);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageRelease);`

The problem is, if I load this SWF into another one like so:

`var contentLoader:Loader = new Loader();
contentLoader.load(new URLRequest("DrawingBoard/DrawingBoard.swf"));`

I get this error:

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at DrawingBoard_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()`

I stop getting this if I comment out the stage event-listeners inside the nested SWF. I'm thinking this is because the loaded SWF isn't being added to the timeline immediately. So, could I add the stage event-listeners in that external SWF, only after it's stage has been initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` inside constructor of external loaded SWF's main class like so:

`addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);`

```
 function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
 {
     //You can access stage object here
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stageClick);
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageRelease);
 }
```

UPDATE:

For timeline code you can use `Event.ACTIVATE`. like so,

```
addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onActivate);

function onActivate(e:Event):void
{

    //remove this listener if you want to dispatch it only once
    removeEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onActivate);
}
```

But be careful. This event will dispatched every time you will come back to stage (e.g. From desktop to you application). So remove it if you want only once.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get the error anymore. But the external SWF's listeners don't get added when I run it on it's own, and only get added when the SWF is loaded into the parent one.

Is there any event that would be triggered inside the external SWF as well, like the onload event in JS?

Comment: Do you have Document Class with your external SWF's? or you are adding the above code directly on Timeline.

Comment: I'm adding it directly on the timeline

Comment: Event.ACTIVATE isn't getting triggered once the SWF gets loaded. But you did solve my problem, I use ADDED_TO_STAGE to add event-listeners in the externally loaded SWF. I just comment it out when working in the external SWF. Thanks!